# How do I pass client through in messageUpdate using an eventHandler in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
const {} = require("discord.js");
```

```
module.exports = (oldMessage, newMessage) => { //passes the old message and new message as arguments
    try {
        if(oldMessage.author.bot) { //if bot edits a message it does not log and just returns
            return;
        }
        if (!oldMessage.author.bot) {
            const channel = (client).channels.cache.get('1095586244890734644'); //the channel to log edited messages
    
            console.log('--------------------------------------------------\n\nChannel: ' + oldMessage.channel + '\nAuthor: ' + oldMessage.author + '\nOld message: ' + oldMessage.content + 
            '\nDate and time: ' + oldMessage.createdAt + '\nNew message: ' + newMessage.content + '\nDate and time updated: ' + newMessage.createdAt + 
            '\n\n--------------------------------------------------'); //logs edited message in console
    
            channel.send('--------------------------------------------------\n\nChannel: ' + oldMessage.channel + '\nAuthor: ' + oldMessage.author + '\nOld message: ' + oldMessage.content + 
            '\nDate and time: ' + oldMessage.createdAt + '\nNew message: ' + newMessage.content + '\nDate and time updated: ' + newMessage.createdAt + 
            '\n\n--------------------------------------------------'); //logs edited messages in the channel
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`There was an error ${error}`); //if an error occurs this will log in the console
    }
};
```

How do I pass `client` through here, I've tried passing 3 arguments alongside `oldMessage` and `newMessage` but the arguments can only be those two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to pass the `client` as it's already available on the `Message` objects you receive:

```js
module.exports = (oldMessage, newMessage) => {
  const { client } = oldMessage;
  // now you can use client
  // ...
};
```